# Php программирование и telegram API

Tags: php, html, form, telegram

Есть код на php с использованием Telegram API. Код должен работать таким образом, чтобы он брал значения, введенные в контактную форму на сайте, компилировал все данные в vcf файл (vcard) и отправлялся в группу в телеграмме.
При исполнении кода в чат приходит сообщение Resource Id, а должен прийти именно файл vcf, который потом я могу сохранить в телефонную книгу.
Подскажите, что неправильно!!!!??? `

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['user_name'];
$phone = $_POST['user_phone'];
$email = $_POST['user_email'];
$token = "token";
$chat_id = "chat";
$arr = array(
  'Имя пользователя: ' => $name,
  'Телефон: ' => $phone,
  'Email' => $email
);

foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
  $txt .= "<b>".$key."</b> ".$value."%0A";
};
$fp = fopen("file.vcf","w");
fwrite($fp, $txt);

$sendToTelegram = fopen("https://api.telegram.org/bot{$token}/sendMessage?chat_id={$chat_id}&parse_mode=html&text={$fp}","r");

if ($sendToTelegram) {
  header('Location: index.html');
} else {
  echo "Error";
}
?>
```

`

Comment: Файлы посылаются методом sendDocument. А никак не sendMessage. Соответственно и формировать надо по другому.

Comment: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#senddocument